# Вход в телеграмм аккаунт с помощью номера, pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

У меня есть основной бот, через который будет выполняться вход в аккаунты. Боту будут отправлять сначала номер, потом код с телеграма.

Как это осуществить с помощью pyrogram(имею ввиду сам вход в аккаунты)

Comment: [Официальная документация](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня вышло как то так:

```
async def test(phone_number):
    api_id = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_id
    api_hash = API.TelegramDesktop.Generate().api_hash
    app = Client("my_account", phone_number=phone_number, api_id=api_id, 
api_hash=api_hash)
    await app.connect()
    sCode = await app.send_code(phone_number)
    code = input('Enter auth code: ')
    await app.sign_in(phone_number, sCode.__dict__['phone_code_hash'], code)
    await app.send_message('me', 'test')
```

Вместо строки code = input('Enter auth code: ') вы можете запросить в боте у юзера код, ну думаю ход мыслей понятен.